# Listing currently bound global variables in lisp

Tags: lisp, global-variables, common-lisp

I am quite new to Lisp and was wondering:
Is there a way to list all (user-defined) global variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility would be to check which of the symbols of a package are `boundp`:

```
(defun user-defined-variables (&optional (package :cl-user))
  (loop with package = (find-package package)
        for symbol being the symbols of package
        when (and (eq (symbol-package symbol) package)
                  (boundp symbol))
          collect symbol))
```

It returns a list of bound symbols that are not inherited from another package.

```
CL-USER> (user-defined-variables)     ; fresh session
NIL
CL-USER> 'foo                         ; intern a symbol
FOO
CL-USER> (defun bar () 'bar)          ; define a function
BAR
CL-USER> (defparameter *baz* 'baz)    ; define a global variable
*BAZ*
CL-USER> (user-defined-variables)
(*BAZ*)                               ; only returns the global variable
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there's no perfectly general way to do this, since you won't be able to find global variables for uninterned symbols.

Comment: Almost: BOUNDP checks for bindings, so it would return T for a dynamic LET bound variable,  even though there might be no global value...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and also for the comments to the answer. @JoshuaTaylor I'm afraid I don't know what an 'uninterned symbol' is. @RainerJoswig I guess  I don't understand either how BOUNDP works as I now wonder why the function `bar` in danlei's example session is not returned. Is bar not 'bound' to some place in memory? And in what way does a dynamic variable bound by LET differ from a global variable?

Comment: @ben_za [**boundp**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_boundp.htm) looks at value bindings.  [**fboundp**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fbound.htm) looks at function bindings.  For global bindings, these are looking at the values of the **symbol-value** and **symbol-function** of the symbol.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes, that's right and a good catch. However, I *assume* the question is more about use at toplevel in the REPL for interactive purposes, and for that it would be of use nonetheless.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Also a good catch. Not that relevant for the use case I assumed, but that's just an assumption, and it's good that you and Rainer point out the corner cases.

Comment: And while we're at it: It wouldn't work for the `deflex` macros out there either. (At least the ones I have seen.)

Comment: @ben_za What Rainer meant was something like this: `(let ((quux 'quux)) (declare (special quux)) (user-defined-variables))`. `user-defined-variables` would also return `quux`, even if it's not globally declared special. (It's still a user defined special variable, but not a global one.)

Comment: Another case is constants.  They're bound, but they're not variables.  You can check if `(not (constantp symbol))`.  You can check all symbols in all packages with the `do-all-symbols` macro.  Finally, most Lisp implementations have `variable-information`, a function that operates on environments.